# Cannot run application using Java Web Start 7 if href attribute in jnlp contains query string

Tags: java, java-web-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [url parameters in jnlp href attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235872/url-parameters-in-jnlp-href-attribute)

Java Web Start 7 cannot run application if there is query string in href attribute in jnlp file.
For example:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Test.jnlp?query_string">
...
</jnlp>
```

There are no any errors. Web Start just does not run application.

But this jnlp could be processed by Java Web Start 6 without any problems.

Is this a bug in Java Web Start 7?
Or using query string in href attribute is not correct by some reason?

**UPDATE:**
There is no such problem in jdk1.7.0_04.
But this problem exists in jdk1.7.0_07.

**UPDATE:**
Bug was introduced in  jdk1.7.0_06.

Comment: *"Is this a bug in Java Web Start 7?"* Is thee any mention of it in the bug database?

Comment: I created bug report. But it is not visible on the Sun Developer Network yet.

Comment: *"I created bug report."*  +1 Please keep us informed as to progress.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/12235872/url-parameters-in-jnlp-href-attribute isnt it the same prob?